# Finding a number in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have an array like this

```
array: [
'Student 1|##|100|@@|Third answer', 
'Student 2|##|10|@@|Third Answer ',
'Student 10|##|50|@@|Third Answer'
]
```

In it **100** represents the *id* of the first item of the array, **10** represents the *id* of the second item of the array and **50** is the *id* of the third item and so on.

I also have a variable whose value is equal to the *id* which can be **100** or **10** or **50**.

```
var id = data.myId
```

I need to check if the id exists in the array.

So if the *id* is **10** and I do `array.includes(id.toString())` it won't return true unless my array is like:

```
array: [
   'Student 1|##|100|@@|Third answer', 
   'Student 2|##|10|@@|Third Answer ',
   'Student 10|##|50|@@|Third Answer',
   '10'
]
```

So how do I do that. I am guessing I have to use regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to check if the id exists in the array.

Use `some`, `split` and check the 3rd item after splitting each item of the string item.

```
var has10 = array.some( s => s.split( "|" )[2] == "10" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var array = [
  'Student 1|##|100|@@|Third answer',
  'Student 2|##|10|@@|Third Answer ',
  'Student 10|##|50|@@|Third Answer'
];
var id = "10";
var hasId = array.some( s => s.split( "|" )[2] == id );

console.log( hasId );
```

Comment: Even simpler : `var has10 = array.some( s => s.split( "|" )[2] == id );`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree about `some`, removed `filter`. For some reason, `filter` is the first thing I think about :)

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, I arrived at the similar solution, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I could see you were editing whilst I was posting this :)

Comment: Or since the OP specifically called out regex: `var rex = new RegExp("^[^|]+\\|[^|]+\\|" + id + "\\|[^|]+\\|[^|]+$"); var has10 = array.some(s => rex.test(s));` :-) But unless a rex is really required, `split` seems better to me.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks, I had no idea about filter or some... This works... But you can remove the hardcoded 10 and use it like this if you are giving an id variable in the answer `var has10 = array.some( s => s.split( "|" )[2] == id );`

Comment: @DragonBorn I have removed the same from demo.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks Accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **[Array#.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** with this regex **[`\|10\|`](https://regex101.com/r/mWBHlD/1)**:

```
let reg = new RegExp("\\|" + id + "\\|");
```

It will give you the first element matching the regex or an empty array if there's no match.

```js
var array = [
  'Student 1|##|100|@@|Third answer',
  'Student 2|##|10|@@|Third Answer ',
  'Student 10|##|50|@@|Third Answer'
];
var id = 10;
let reg = new RegExp("\\|" + id + "\\|");
var result = array.find(function(item) {
  return item.match(reg);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. This will do too.

Comment: @DragonBorn You are welcome.